# Is there a way to make IFTT send facebook message

Tags: facebook-messenger

I want to send facebook message to a certain list of facebook accounts, originating from my facebook account each time my Netatmo weather station detects CO2 above certain levels.

It'd be obvious to use IFTT for that, but there's no action channel for sending facebook message.

Answer (score 1):

IFTT does not seem to support Facebook Messenger.

Take a look at their Facebook channel page: https://ifttt.com/facebook

This page lists all triggers and actions that can be used with this channel.

[image: IFTT Facebook channel triggers and actions overview]